# High FPS config for Left 4 Dead 2

Tags: left-4-dead-2

A friend of mine is having a little trouble running Left 4 Dead 2 because of a weak graphics card. He consistently gets around 10 FPS. I've been looking around for a high FPS config for this game, but I haven't found any. I had the same trouble running TF2 on my netbook once, and using one of these configs was amazingly effective.

**Is there any config file (`autoexe.cfg`) out there to minimize all possible settings and maximize performance for L4D2?**

*Note: I did find 2 configs. But the [first one](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1034100) doesn't really minimize settings (it only optimizes stuff), and the [second](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/action/left4dead2/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-52546393&pid=960510) is just a TF2 config copy-pasted.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running in software mode? You have to edit the shortcut to L4D2 and add the option `-soft` as listed [here](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options). It's horrible to look at but if he has a faster CPU it may increase performance. We used to play Unreal and Half-Life this way at my workplace using our crappy onboard graphics cards.

Alternately, try OpenGL `-gl` or Direct3D `-d3d` modes to see which works the best.

`-autoconfig` option might also be worth checking out:

> Restores video and performance settings to default for the current hardware detected. Ignores settings inside any .cfg files until this parameter is removed.